# Set (override) locale for Embedded Service SDK

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, snap-ins, embedded

We're using Embedded Service SDK in our react app for ServiceChat functionality.

Processing a case with different locale settings in the Salesforce system and on a specific user device, SDK will load with device locale, but we would like to rely on user settings in the Salesforce system.

Is it possible to run (call \ fire \ launch) SDK with the desired locale, but not with a device locale?

**UPD:**
The question is whether the mobile SDK supports setting the desired locale bypassing standard behavior. The standard behavior is to take the locale from the device settings, but we need to set the locale for the SDK different from the device settings.

Comment: What about using ``LanguageLocaleKey`` and ``LocaleSidKey`` fields from a ``User`` object? Based on that you can set specific locales on mobile before displaying the data.

[User | SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)

Comment: question updated

Comment: Embedded Service SDK (a.k.a Snap-In's) is a Service Cloud product that is not the Salesforce Mobile SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from Salesforce Service Cloud support about both systems iOS and Android.

They recommended using some kind of hacky solution for android devices - [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#setLocale(java.util.Locale)) : setLocale() method on Configuration class level.

And for ios system support confirmed the impossibility of any overriding device locale settings after iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `LanguageLocaleKey` and `LocaleSidKey` fields from a context `User`. Based on that you can set specific locales on mobile before displaying the data.

From [User | SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm):

**`LocaleSidKey`**

> Required. This field is a restricted picklist field. The value of the
>   field affects formatting and parsing of values, especially numeric
>   values, in the user interface. It does not affect the API. The field
>   values are named according to the language, and country if necessary,
>   using two-letter ISO codes. The set of names is based on the ISO
>   standard. You can also manually set a user’s locale in the user
>   interface, and then use that value for inserting or updating other
>   users via the API.

**`LanguageLocaleKey`**

> Required. The user’s language, such as “French” or “Chinese
>   (Traditional).” Label is Language.
>
> **NOTE:**
>
> In API version 47.0 and later, when using the DescribeSObjectResult
>   API to return PicklistEntry values from this picklist, the `active`
>   value indicates whether the language is in the user’s **Displayed
>   Languages** (`true`) or the user’s **Available Languages** (`false`). All other
>   languages aren’t in the returned `active` value array.
>
> In API version 46.0 and earlier, the PicklistEntry `active` values
>   indicate whether the language is in either the user’s **Displayed
>   Languages** or **Available Languages** lists (`true`) or not in either list
>   (`false`).

These fields are not available through `UserAccount` class in [MobileSDK](http://forcedotcom.github.io/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/index.html) but having [other fields](http://forcedotcom.github.io/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/com/salesforce/androidsdk/accounts/UserAccount.html) from this class you should be able to retrieve locales by REST/SOAP request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But we have no problem determining the desired locale. The question is whether the mobile SDK supports setting the desired locale bypassing standard behavior. The standard behavior is to take the language standard from the device settings, but we need to set the locale for the SDK different from the device settings.